# api key problem - how to convert curl to python requests for accessing ftpbrick

Tags: python, python-2.7, curl, python-requests

Going over [this guide](https://developers.brickftp.com/#file-uploading) I'm trying to download a file from my ftpbrick via python requests.

I managed to do this using bash with the following command:

```
 curl https://MY_SUB_DOMAIN.brickftp.com/api/rest/v1/files/MY_FILE_NAME -u MY_API_KEY:x -H 'Accept: application/json'
```

which returns me a response with a uri for download. Now I want to do the same from python. I tried converting it myself, and even used [this online tool](https://curl.trillworks.com/) for verification. This is what I got:

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: requests.post('https://MY_SUB_DOMAIN.brickftp.com/api/rest/v1/files/MY_FILE_NAME', headers={'Accept': 'application/json'}, auth=(MY_API_KEY, 'x'))
```

but that eventually led to (after typo fix):

```
Out[7]: <Response [400]>
```

What am I doing wrong?

*I'm aware of [brickfpt for python 3.6](https://github.com/octoenergy/BrickFTP). I however, must still support Py2.7*

Comment: First of all try `headers={'Accept': 'application/json'}` (without the : after `Accept`)

Comment: `requests.post('https://MY_SUB_DOMAIN.brickftp.com/api/rest/v1/files/MY_FILE_NAME', headers={'Accept': 'application/json'}, auth=(MY_API_KEY, 'x'))` ?

Comment: @sneep. Fixed it and got Response 400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your curl command sends a `GET` request, while the Python one does a `POST`. Try changing `requests.post(...)` to `requests.get(...)`.